# In spinner items if select particular item means only the edit text has be go enable and get item to add spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I am beginner to android... Am trying following: In list of spinner items if select the one particular item (Example:Extra) means only the edittext text has to go enable.Remaining times it want to be disable..And I've to add extra item while select the particular item..... The sample code will help me lot...Thank you

Comment: Spinner colourSpinner = (Spinner)
        findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.colors, 
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: **XML**     <string-array name="colours">
<item>Red</item>
<item>Blue</item>
<item>White</item>
<item>Yellow</item>
<item>Black</item>
<item>Green</item>
<item>Purple</item>
<item>Orange</item>
<item>Grey</item>
</string-array>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the EditText Visible code in Spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() 
in that u check the selected item text is Extra u write the visible code there